# Call from Lambda to get secret from Secrets Manager is very slow

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, vpc-endpoint

Recently I've started to use Secrets Manager to read credentials from Lambda, and I noticed that reading a secret from SM takes several seconds. Introducing VPC interface endpoint as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html#vpc-endpoint didn't help, I see the same response time.

In CloudTrail I see that created VPC endpoint is used to call Secrets Manager.

Did anyone have similar issue?

Comment: That is strange. I have Lambdas inside a VPC calling secrets manager and they don't take that long. Can you provide more details? Maybe the code that retrieves it perhaps and how the handler calls it?